# How to click using query selector

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am having a list of navigation items that on load click the first element from the list

```
<li class="nav-item"  v-for="(checkoutplan, index) in checkoutplans" :key="checkoutplan.id">
     <a  class="nav-link" :class="{ 'active show' : index === 0 }" href="#settings" data-toggle="tab" @click="editModal(checkoutplan)">Checkout Plan {{index +1}}</a>
</li>
```

What i am trying

```
 document.querySelector("li[class='nav-item']").click()
```

nor

```
document.querySelector("li.nav-item:first-child").click()
```

It is not working

```
  created() {
        axios.get("api/checkoutplan")
        .then(({ data }) => {this.checkoutplans = data;document.querySelector("a.nav-link:first-child").click();});
    }
```

Comment: Typo in html-tag name in selector?

Comment: I corrected it  then also it is not working

Comment: `created() {
        axios.get("api/checkoutplan")
        .then(({ data }) => {this.checkoutplans = data;document.querySelector("a.nav-link:first-child").click();});
    }`

elements are not ready when u run this function in `created` . so move the click event to mounted. 

`mounted(){
document.querySelector("a.nav-link:first-child").click();
}`

Comment: No it is not working . I have added document.querySelector("a.nav-link:first-child").click() to mounted

Comment: update your code to jsfiddle or codepen. i will help to fix

Answer (score 1):

First add `refs` to your HTML (at `a` tag) as

```
<li class="nav-item"  v-for="(checkoutplan, index) in checkoutplans" :key="checkoutplan.id">
     <a  :id="'nav' + index" :ref="'nav' + index" class="nav-link" :class="{ 'active show' : index === 0 }" href="#settings" data-toggle="tab" @click="editModal(checkoutplan)">Checkout Plan {{index +1}}</a>
</li>
```

Now in vuejs

```
$(this.$refs.nav0).click(function(){
    //nav0 is beacuse you want first element & first element index is 0
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*as your comment ,  I tried like below in mounted method (not created) .Beware `nextTick` is required when vue element is modify by data*

```js
new Vue({
 el: "#app",
 data: {
  checkoutplans : []
 },
 methods: {
   editModal : function(param) {
     console.log(param);
   }
 },
 mounted: function() {
   this.checkoutplans = [{id:1},{id:2}];
   this.$nextTick(() => {
   this.$el.querySelector("li.nav-item:first-child a").click();
   });
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<ul>
<li class="nav-item"  v-for="(checkoutplan, index) in checkoutplans" :key="checkoutplan.id">
     <a  class="nav-link" :class="{ 'active show' : index === 0 }" href="#settings" data-toggle="tab" @click="editModal(checkoutplan)">Checkout Plan {{index +1}}</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Your code seem to click first li after api called ! So the method you will call is `editModal({firstItem})` . How about calling the method directly without clicking like

```
axios.get("api/checkoutplan")
    .then(({ data }) => {this.checkoutplans = data;this.editModal(this.checkoutplans[0]) // direct call });
```

> Created method is not ready state for document element so you can't call document element in that method

Comment: it is  working but tab is not changed to first element

Answer (score -1):

```
var button = document.querySelector("input[type=button]");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert("button was clicked");
})
```

Comment: I need to select first element from the list

Comment: Code w/o explanation is more or less useless.

Answer (score -1):

You binded click event in href `a.nav-link` tag. not in  so try

```
document.querySelector("a.nav-link:first-child").click()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
document.querySelector('.nav-link');
```

please try this code.

Comment: Code w/o explanation is more or less useless.